# Trying To Communicate With a User Mode Program Using Flt Functions (In Kernel)

Tags: c++, windows, driver

I am trying to communicate with a user mode program via Windows driver using Flt functions.

And when I build the program (on VS) I get a lot of [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXp64.png):
I can't understand what those errors mean.

That's my code:

```
    #include <Ntifs.h>
    #include <ntddk.h>
    #include <fltKernel.h>
    #include <WinDef.h>
    #include <Psapi.h>



    #pragma comment(lib, "fltlib")

    UNICODE_STRING name = RTL_CONSTANT_STRING(L"\\Test");
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sd;
    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES attr;
    PFLT_FILTER gFilterHandle;
    LARGE_INTEGER timeout;
    PFLT_PORT FilterPort;
    PFLT_PORT SendClientPort;
    NTSTATUS status;

    NTSTATUS createCommunication();
    NTSTATUS PortConnectNotify(PFLT_PORT ClientPort, PVOID ServerPortCookie, PVOID ConnectionContext, ULONG SizeOfContext,
                        PVOID* ConnectionPortCookie);
    NTSTATUS PortMessageNotify(PVOID PortCookie, PVOID InputBuffer, ULONG InputBufferLength, PVOID OutputBuffer,
                        ULONG OutputBufferLength, PULONG ReturnOutputBufferLength);
    void PortDisconnectNotify(PVOID ConnectionCookie);


    void SampleUnload(_In_ PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject)
    {
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(DriverObject);
    DbgPrint("Sample driver Unload called\n");
    timeout.QuadPart = 10000 * 50;
    status = createCommunication();
    }


    void sCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx(PEPROCESS process, HANDLE pid, PPS_CREATE_NOTIFY_INFO createInfo)
    {
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(createInfo);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(process);

    WCHAR path[MAX_PATH];
    if(!GetProcessImageFileNameW(pid, path, MAX_PATH))
    {
    DbgPrint("Can't get the process image name");
    return;
    }
    LPWSTR hash[35]; //Getting the hash from the replay message
    status = FltSendMessage(gFilterHandle, &SendClientPort, path, MAX_PATH, hash, reinterpret_cast<ULONG*>(35),
                        &timeout);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
    DbgPrint("Can't send the message and");
    return;
    }
    DbgPrint("The hash of %wZ is %wZ", path, hash);
    }


    extern "C"
    NTSTATUS
    DriverEntry(_In_ PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, _In_ PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath)
    {
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(RegistryPath);
    DriverObject->DriverUnload = SampleUnload;

    DbgPrint("Sample driver Load called\n");

    //When createComunication()
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
    DbgPrint("Can't create the connection");
    return status;
    }


    DbgPrint("Finish");

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
    }


    NTSTATUS PortConnectNotify(PFLT_PORT ClientPort, PVOID ServerPortCookie, PVOID ConnectionContext, ULONG SizeOfContext,
                        PVOID* ConnectionPortCookie)
    {
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(ServerPortCookie);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(ConnectionContext);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(SizeOfContext);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(ConnectionPortCookie);

    SendClientPort = ClientPort;

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
    }


    void PortDisconnectNotify(PVOID ConnectionCookie)
    {
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(ConnectionCookie);

    FltCloseClientPort(gFilterHandle, &SendClientPort);
    SendClientPort = nullptr;
    }


    NTSTATUS PortMessageNotify(PVOID PortCookie, PVOID InputBuffer, ULONG InputBufferLength, PVOID OutputBuffer,
                        ULONG OutputBufferLength, PULONG ReturnOutputBufferLength)
    {
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(PortCookie);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(InputBuffer);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(InputBufferLength);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(OutputBuffer);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(OutputBufferLength);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(ReturnOutputBufferLength);

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
    }


    NTSTATUS createCommunication()
    {
    status = FltBuildDefaultSecurityDescriptor(&sd, FLT_PORT_ALL_ACCESS);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
    return status;


    InitializeObjectAttributes(&attr, &name, OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE | OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE, nullptr, sd);
    status = FltCreateCommunicationPort(gFilterHandle, &FilterPort, &attr, nullptr,
                                    (PFLT_CONNECT_NOTIFY)PortConnectNotify,
                                    (PFLT_DISCONNECT_NOTIFY)PortDisconnectNotify,
                                    (PFLT_MESSAGE_NOTIFY)PortMessageNotify, 1);

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
    return status;

    FltFreeSecurityDescriptor(sd);
    status = FltStartFiltering(gFilterHandle);
    return status;
    }
```

Maybe my pragma is incorrect?
How can I solve it?
I am very new in the driver world so sorry for being newbie.
Thanks for all the helpers!

Comment: Looks like you forgot to link to a library.

Comment: The documentation for FltSendMessage: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/fltkernel/nf-fltkernel-fltsendmessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/fltkernel/nf-fltkernel-fltsendmessage) indicates you need to link to `FltMgr.lib`. Did you do that?

Comment: Now I changed to #pragma comment(lib, "FltMgr.lib"). But I am still getting the same errors

Comment: What does it mean "Looks like you forgot to link to a library"?

Comment: This type of error in a windows API is usually a missed link.

Comment: ***But I am still getting the same errors*** Not sure why. I know Microsoft makes mistakes in their documentation from time to time but I would not expect that.

Comment: Do you any other idea?

Comment: I don't. The error indicates that there is a linking problem with the library that implements these functions.

Comment: The `#pragma comment(lib)` directive doesn't work for driver code. You need to add the file to the library input page in the project configuration.

Comment: Thank you for the response @Luke, how can I do that?